# Need to create new record from beginning when case value matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know that if case statement find any first match for that record, it will not check rest of the condition for that record(in my case record 2).

I tried `UNION` too which is gives me the right result but with some extra records. Any approach would do it for me.

```
create table #temp (Name varchar(100), ColA int, ColB int, ColC int, ColD int)

insert into #temp (name, ColA,ColB, ColC, ColD)
values ('Name1', 1, null, null, null)
      ,('Name2', 1, 1   , null, null)


select name,
case 
    when ColA = 1 then 'some value'
    when ColB = 1 then 'Other value'
    when ColC = 1 then 'some2 value'
    when ColD = 1 then 'some3 value'
end CaseValues
from #temp

select * from #temp


/*when you run this case statement I get only two record. But I need three records for each value matched as below:

    Name    CaseValues

1   Name1   Some value
2   Name2   some vaule
3   Name2   other value
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, 'some value'
  from from #temp
 where ColA = 1 
union 
select name, 'Other value'
  from #temp
 where ColB = 1
union 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
select name, 'some value' from #temp where colA is not null 
union all
select name, 'Other value' from #temp where colB is not null
union all
select name, 'some2 value' from #temp where colC is not null
union all
select name, 'some3 value' from #temp where colD is not null
```

Comment: the condition is 1 not not null and that answer was already posted